# Displaying an array of data in to a table of 4 columns

Tags: php

I have a php array which contains 45 items that I would displayed into a table of 4 columns.  The code below is what I have.

```
$output = '<table border="1">';

for($tr=0; $tr<=count($question_answers); $tr++)
{

    $output .=  "<tr>";
    for($td=1; $td<=$cols; $td++){
        $output .=  "<td>" . $question_answers[$tr] . "</td>";
    }
    $output .= "</tr>";
}

$output .= "</table>";
```

How do I split that data so that it split into 4 columns? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it needed to split into 4 columns randomly?

Comment: Can you please show how you want to show your data

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do it. You're already using a for loop and $tr++ which increments 1 each time. You could increment 4 instead, and create another loop to output the four inside that. Or you could use array_chunk() and iterate through those arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: What I am trying to achieve a table with a maximum of 12 rows and 4 columns.  The first column would be from 1 to 12, second column 13 - 24, third column 25 - 36 and fourth column 37 etc...

Comment: Updated my answer for your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $output = '<table border="1">';

    for($tr=0; $tr<=count($question_answers); $tr++)
    {

        $output .=  "<tr>";
        for($td=1; $td<=$cols; $td++){
            $output .=  "<td>" . $question_answers[$tr] . "</td>".($tr % 4 == 0 ? "</tr><tr>" : "");
        }
        $output .= "</tr>";
    }

    $output .= "</table>";
```

Or for this case: "What I am trying to achieve a table with a maximum of 12 rows and 4 columns. The first column would be from 1 to 12, second column 13 - 24, third column 25 - 36 and fourth column 37 etc... "

```
$output = '<table border="1">';

        for($tr=0; $tr<12; $tr++){
            $output .=  "<tr>";
            for($td=0; $td<=3; $td++){
                if(!empty($question_answers[$td*12+$tr]))
                 $output .=  "<td>" .$question_answers[$td*12+$tr] . "</td>";
            }
            $output .= "</tr>";
        }


    $output .= "</table>";
```

The result would be: 
http://joxi.ru/E2pbzzvf8Xp8rY